# Using an enum to specify the XmlElemnent name with JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb

I have an enum something like this:

```
@XmlType
@XmlEnum(String.class)
enum VEHICLE_TYPE{CAR, TRUCK, SUV}
```

This is used in a class like this:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Vehicle {
    VEHICLE_TYPE vehicleType;
    String edition;
    String year;
}
```

Elsewhere, a list of Vehicles is part of another object, and when it is marshaled I get:

```
<vehicle>
    <vehicle_type>CAR</vehicle_type>
    <edition>27420</edition>
    <year>2016</year>
</vehicle>
```

But, what I really want is that the tag-name of the "vehicle" element should be based on the enum, giving me:

```
<CAR>
    <vehicle_type>CAR</vehicle_type>
    <edition>27420</edition>
    <year>2016</year>
</CAR>
```

Is there a way to do this using JAXB annotations?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This is not how you should use XML. Tag names should only describe the structure of the XML, and not contain content information like this.

Comment: If you're asking why the XML tags should say things like <car> instead of <vehicle>, with "car" as a value inside, then the answer is that the external system I'm interfacing with requires it like this.
I realize I can create a POJO that has various fields, with the various names, but have them all as null except one. But, that's messy. 
So, my plan was to simply build the XML without JAXB.

Comment: JAXB is not really designed for this kind of thing, so I think this would indeed be easier to do if you would use one of the other Java XML APIs: DOM, SAX or StAX.

Comment: Thank you. I'm planning on using Groovy's markup builder. Your comment is helpful because it gives me a reason to advise the external group about future schemas they're in the process of designating.